# How to extract information from web page

Tags: javascript, html, mozilla

I'm looking for a way to automatically extract information from a web page, more specifically an online game (https://www.virtualregatta.com/fr/offshore-jeu/).

In the game, I want to extract/copy the position of the boat. With Mozilla and its debug tools, I used the network debugger and I saw an HTML POST request containing what I want.

It seems that we receive as a response a json containing a structure with latitude/longitude.

This is perfect to me, but I want a more user friendly way to get it and I would need advices. Problem is that I'm really a beginner in web development haha.

- Is it possible to do this using a script ? (But I suppose it will be complicated to first log into the game)
- Is it possible to create a basic Mozilla plugin which would be able to catch the request/response and copy the position to clipboard for me ?
- anything else ?

EDIT:
I've tried using a Mozilla plugin, and I achieved to add a listener on POST request. I see the request to get the boat information but I can't find a way to get the json response in JS.

```
function logURL(responseDetails) {
    console.log(responseDetails);
}

browser.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(
    logURL,
    {urls: ["*://*.virtualregatta.com/getboatinfos"]}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome I use [Broomo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/broomo-javascript-jquery/hmkipcoboafepjhahnpifcbfbjlkiblf) for this purposes. It helps you to add scripts in web pages, you can console.log the POST you found, and of course you can create functions and Use the webpage Backend.

In firefox I found this one [js-injector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-js-injector/). But I didn't use it before.

Update:

Now there are a new extension for both browsers:

- Chrome: [ABC JS-CSS Injector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/abc-js-css-injector/dnoagfebjndkhkabjkkoeeijnjpmbimj)
- Firefox: [ABC JS-CSS Injector](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/abc-js-css-injector/)

Comment: Ok nice, and how would you intercept the post requests/responses in javascript ?

Comment: I managed to add a listerner on post response using browser.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener, but I can't see the json result.